# Django Rest Framework routing with primary key prefix

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, routes

I'm using DRF `DefaultRouter` as follows.

```
# urls.py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('book', BookingViewSet, basename='booking')
router.register('book/<int:bk>/reservation', ReservationViewSet, basename='reservation')

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

---

```
# view
class ReservationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ReservationSerializer
    queryset = Reservation.objects.all() # for testing only
```

---

But when I visit the URL `/book/1/reservation/` it says no url pattern found.

```
lending/ ^book/<int:bk>/reservation/$ [name='reservation-list']
lending/ ^book/<int:bk>/reservation\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='reservation-list']
lending/ ^book/<int:bk>/reservation/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='reservation-detail']
lending/ ^book/<int:bk>/reservation/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='reservation-detail'] 

The current path, lending/book/1/reservation/, didn’t match any of these.
```

I'm using `bk` to capture book id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because it implements the `<int:bk>` as regex, so *without* any interpretation. Probably the simplest way to do this is with two routers:

```
router1 = DefaultRouter()
router1.register('book', BookingViewSet, basename='booking')

router2 = DefaultRouter()
router2.register('reservation', ReservationViewSet, basename='reservation')

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router1.urls)),
   path('book/<int:bk>/', include(router2.urls)),
]
```

In the `ReservationViewSet` you can then for example filter with `bk`:

```
class ReservationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ReservationSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Reservation.objects.filter(book_id=self.kwargs['bk'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add this to the accepted answer ... You can also do this with the same router, just embed the pk in the URL in regex form as the error message suggests:

```
# urls.py
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('book', BookingViewSet, basename='booking')
router.register('book/(?P<bk>[^/.]+)/reservation', ReservationViewSet, basename='reservation')

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

You can then access the `bk` argument in your view using `self.kwargs['bk']`.